# @JsonFormat writes string even with NUMBER shape for a String property

Tags: java, json, string, jackson

Even with the `NUMBER` shape why its printing string with double quotes?

```
@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.NUMBER)
private String count;
...

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Test test =new Test();
test.setCount("20");

String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(test);
System.out.println(jsonString);
```

`JSON` result:

```
{
  "count" : "20"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@JsonFormat` annotation is an only suggestion and result depends from given custom serialiser which will be used to serialise given value. In your case, `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer` will be used to serialise `count` value. This serialiser does not implement any special behaviour. Just simple writing value as `JSON String`. From other side, `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NumberSerializer` respects `@JsonFormat` annotation and if you set `STRING` shape it will produce `JSON String` instead of `JSON Number`.

So, you always have to check type serialiser implementation to answer questions like this.

Comment: Is there a way to log which implementation is used?

Comment: @zygimantus, serialiser which will be used depends from the property type. If `@JsonSerialize` annotation is used it takes a precedence.